# SQL syntax query order by

Tags: sql

```
SELECT TCID, START_TIME, RESULT, 
       cast(START_TIME as date) as m_date,
       max(cast(START_TIME as time)) as max_time
FROM jenkins_result.JENKINS_RESULT
WHERE TCID = 'A330506'
GROUP BY TCID, m_date;
```

This is my data:

ID      TCID    START_DATE          RESULT
1545240 A435727 2020-11-08 03:11:43 PASS
1545334 A435727 2020-11-08 03:19:53 PASS
1547439 A435727 2020-11-09 03:11:52 PASS
1547621 A435727 2020-11-09 03:20:05 PASS
1548388 A435727 2020-11-09 07:51:29 PASS
1558801 A435727 2020-11-12 00:11:10 PASS
1561899 A435727 2020-11-12 08:48:59 PASS

I want to get result of each TCID follow date like this

ID      TCID    START_DATE          RESULT
1545334 A435727 2020-11-08 03:19:53 PASS
1548388 A435727 2020-11-09 07:51:29 PASS
1561899 A435727 2020-11-12 08:48:59 PASS

But the result current like that:

1545240 A435727 2020-11-08 03:11:43 PASS    2020-11-08  03:19:53
1547439 A435727 2020-11-09 03:11:52 PASS    2020-11-09  07:51:29
1558801 A435727 2020-11-12 00:11:10 PASS    2020-11-12  08:48:59

```
def connect_cli_server(self):
    connect_success = 0
    if self.ssh_client is None:
        self.ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
        for cnt in range(self.retry_cnt):
            try:
                self.ssh_client.connect(self.ip, 22, self.id, self.pw, timeout=self.time_out,
                                        banner_timeout=self.banner)
                connect_success = 1
                break
            except:
                if cnt < 10:
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))
                if 10 <= cnt < 20:
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))
                else:
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1.5))
                continue
        if not connect_success:
            try:
                self.connect_cli_server_thru_remote_server()
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)
                return False
        return True

    def send_command(self, ssh_client, command):
    chan = ssh_client.get_transport().open_session()
    chan.get_pty()
    fileobject = chan.makefile()
    chan.exec_command(command)
    byteoutput = fileobject.read()
    convetedstring = byteoutput.decode("UTF-8")
    return convetedstring
```

Comment: Sample input and output data would greatly help your question.

Comment: The `order by` seems to match the questions title. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some sample input by sql command

```
create table tbl_mock (
  id int,
  tc int,
  startdate datetime,
  result varchar(20)
);

insert into tbl_mock(id, tc, startdate, result) values (1, 1, '2020/11/12 09:00:00', 'pass');
insert into tbl_mock(id, tc, startdate, result) values (2, 1, '2020/11/12 10:00:00', 'fail');
insert into tbl_mock(id, tc, startdate, result) values (3, 1, '2020/11/12 11:00:00', 'pass');
insert into tbl_mock(id, tc, startdate, result) values (4, 1, '2020/11/13 09:00:00', 'pass');
insert into tbl_mock(id, tc, startdate, result) values (5, 1, '2020/11/13 10:00:00', 'fail');
insert into tbl_mock(id, tc, startdate, result) values (6, 1, '2020/11/13 11:00:00', 'fail');
```

You can try the below sql command to get your result

```
select tbl_a.*
from tbl_mock as tbl_a, 
  (select tc, 
    cast(startdate as date) as m_date,
    max(cast(startdate as time)) as m_time
  from tbl_mock
  group by tc, m_date) as tbl_b
where tbl_a.tc = tbl_b.tc
and timestamp(tbl_b.m_date, tbl_b.m_time) = tbl_a.startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT TCID
      ,START_TIME
      ,RESULT
      ,cast(START_TIME as date) as m_date
      ,max(cast(START_TIME as time)) as max_time
FROM jenkins_result.JENKINS_RESULT
WHERE TCID='A330506'
GROUP BY TCID
        ,START_TIME
        ,RESULT
        ,cast(START_TIME as date)
ORDER BY TCID
        ,m_date;
```

which should be the same as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TCID
               ,START_TIME
               ,RESULT
               ,cast(START_TIME as date) as m_date
               ,max(cast(START_TIME as time)) OVER() as max_time
FROM jenkins_result.JENKINS_RESULT
WHERE TCID='A330506'
ORDER BY TCID
        ,m_date;
```

or if you need to get the `MAX` value per `TCID`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TCID
               ,START_TIME
               ,RESULT
               ,cast(START_TIME as date) as m_date
               ,max(cast(START_TIME as time)) OVER(PARTITION BY TCID) as max_time
FROM jenkins_result.JENKINS_RESULT
WHERE TCID='A330506'
ORDER BY TCID
        ,m_date;
```

Comment: when I use OVER syntax, sql mark this error. I don't know why is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
import os
import numpy as np
import queue

pygame.init()
q = 8
w = 70


def normalize_image(img):
    return pygame.transform.scale(img, (w - 10, w - 10))


agent = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('EmptyAgent.png'))
wumpus = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Wumpus.png'))
gold = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Gold.png'))
pit = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Pit.png'))
agent = normalize_image(agent)
wumpus = normalize_image(wumpus)
gold = normalize_image(gold)
pit = normalize_image(pit)

gr_empty = 0
gr_agent = 4
gr_wumpus = 1
gr_gold = 3
gr_pit = 2

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((q * w, q * w))
xh, yh = q - 1, 0
grid = [[gr_empty] * q for _ in range(q)]
grid[xh][yh] = gr_agent
bg_color = (255, 255, 255)
border_color = (0, 0, 0)
dx = [0,1,0,-1]
dy = [1,0,-1,0]

def bfs():
    vs = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    tracex = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    tracey = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    traced = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    tracex[0][0][0] = 2
    que = queue.Queue()
    que.put((q-1,0,0,0))
    vs[q-1][0][0]=1
    gx, gy, gd, gt = 0, 0, 0, 1000
    while not que.empty():
        (x,y,dir,t) = que.get()
        d=0
        if grid[x][y]==3 and dir<4:
            if gt>t:
                gx, gy, gd, gt = x,y,dir,t
            if vs[x][y][dir+4]==0:
                que.put((x,y,dir+4,t+1))
                vs[x][y][dir+4]=1
                tracex[x][y][dir+4],tracey[x][y][dir+4],traced[x][y][dir+4] = x,y,dir
            continue
        if x==q-1 and y==0 and dir>3:
            return 1000-(t+1)*10, gx, gy, gd, tracex, tracey, traced
        if x<0 or y<0 or x>=q or y>=q:
            continue
        if grid[x][y]==gr_wumpus or grid[x][y]==gr_pit:
            continue
        if dir>3:
            d+=4
            dir-=4
        if vs[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d] == 0:
            que.put((x, y, (dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d, t + 1))
            vs[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = 1
            tracex[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d], tracey[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d], traced[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = x, y, dir
        if vs[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d] == 0:
            que.put((x, y, (dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d, t + 1))
            vs[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = 1
            tracex[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d], tracey[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d], traced[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = x, y, dir
        if x+dx[dir]<0 or x+dx[dir]>=q or y+dy[dir]<0 or y+dy[dir]>=q:
            continue
        if vs[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d] == 0:
            que.put((x + dx[dir], y + dy[dir], dir + d, t + 1))
            vs[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d] = 1
            tracex[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d], tracey[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d], traced[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d] = x, y, dir
    return -1, gx, gy, gd, tracex, tracey, traced

def test():
    grid[q-2][1] = gr_wumpus
    grid[q-3][2] = gr_gold
    grid[q-3][0] = gr_pit
    ans, gx, gy, gd, tracex, tracey, traced = bfs()
    if ans<0:
        ans=-1
    print(ans)
    tx, ty, td = gx, gy, gd
    if ans>=0:
        while 1:
            print(tx, ty, td)
            if tx==q-1 and ty==0:
                break
            xn, yn, dn = int(tracex[tx][ty][td]), int(tracey[tx][ty][td]), int(traced[tx][ty][td])
            tx, ty, td = xn,yn,dn

    # print(tracex[0][0][0])



def draw_img(img, x, y):
    screen.blit(img, (x + 5, y + 5))


def draw():
    x, y = 0, 0
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    for i in range(q):
        for j in range(q):
            if grid[i][j] == gr_agent:
                draw_img(agent, x, y)
            elif grid[i][j] == gr_wumpus:
                draw_img(wumpus, x, y)
            elif grid[i][j] == gr_gold:
                draw_img(gold, x, y)
            elif grid[i][j] == gr_pit:
                draw_img(pit, x, y)
            for k in range(4):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, border_color, (x - k, y - k, w, w), 1)
            x = x + w
        x = 0
        y = y + w


def main():
    test()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mx, my = event.pos
                gy = mx // w
                gx = my // w
                if not grid[gx][gy] == gr_empty:
                    continue
                elif event.button == 1:
                    # Left click
                    grid[gx][gy] = gr_wumpus
                elif event.button == 3:
                    # Scroll slick
                    grid[gx][gy] = gr_gold
                elif event.button == 2:
                    # Middle click
                    grid[gx][gy] = gr_pit
        draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(600)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
import os
import numpy as np
import queue

pygame.init()
q = 3
w = 70


def normalize_image(img):
    return pygame.transform.scale(img, (w - 10, w - 10))


agent = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('EmptyAgent.png'))
wumpus = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Wumpus.png'))
gold = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Gold.png'))
pit = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Pit.png'))
agent = normalize_image(agent)
wumpus = normalize_image(wumpus)
gold = normalize_image(gold)
pit = normalize_image(pit)

gr_empty = 0
gr_agent = 4
gr_wumpus = 1
gr_gold = 3
gr_pit = 2

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((q * w, q * w))
xh, yh = q - 1, 0
grid = [[gr_empty] * q for _ in range(q)]
grid[xh][yh] = gr_agent
bg_color = (255, 255, 255)
border_color = (0, 0, 0)
dx = [0,1,0,-1]
dy = [1,0,-1,0]

def bfs():
    vs = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    tracex = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    tracey = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    traced = np.zeros((q,q,8))
    tracex[0][0][0] = 2
    que = queue.Queue()
    que.put((q-1,0,0,0))
    vs[q-1][0][0]=1
    gx, gy, gd, gt = 0, 0, 0, 1000
    while not que.empty():
        (x,y,dir,t) = que.get()
        d=0
        if grid[x][y]==3 and dir<4:
            if gt>t:
                gx, gy, gd, gt = x,y,dir,t
            if vs[x][y][dir+4]==0:
                que.put((x,y,dir+4,t+1))
                vs[x][y][dir+4]=1
                tracex[x][y][dir+4],tracey[x][y][dir+4],traced[x][y][dir+4] = x,y,dir
            continue
        if x==q-1 and y==0 and dir>3:
            gx, gy, gd, gt = x, y, dir, t
            return 1000-(t+1)*10, gx, gy, gd, tracex, tracey, traced
        if x<0 or y<0 or x>=q or y>=q:
            continue
        if grid[x][y]==gr_wumpus or grid[x][y]==gr_pit:
            continue
        if dir>3:
            d+=4
            dir-=4
        if vs[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d] == 0:
            que.put((x, y, (dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d, t + 1))
            vs[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = 1
            tracex[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d], tracey[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d], traced[x][y][(dir + 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = x, y, dir + d
        if vs[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d] == 0:
            que.put((x, y, (dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d, t + 1))
            vs[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = 1
            tracex[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d], tracey[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d], traced[x][y][(dir - 1 + 4) % 4 + d] = x, y, dir + d
        if x+dx[dir]<0 or x+dx[dir]>=q or y+dy[dir]<0 or y+dy[dir]>=q:
            continue
        if vs[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d] == 0:
            que.put((x + dx[dir], y + dy[dir], dir + d, t + 1))
            vs[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d] = 1
            tracex[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d], tracey[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d], traced[x + dx[dir]][y + dy[dir]][dir + d] = x, y, dir + d
    return -1, gx, gy, gd, tracex, tracey, traced

def test():
    grid[q-2][1] = gr_wumpus
    grid[q-3][2] = gr_gold
    grid[q-3][0] = gr_pit
    ans, gx, gy, gd, tracex, tracey, traced = bfs()
    if ans<0:
        ans=-1
    print(ans)
    tx, ty, td = gx, gy, gd
    if ans>=0:
        while 1:
            print(tx, ty, td)
            if tx==q-1 and ty==0 and td==0:
                break
            xn, yn, dn = int(tracex[tx][ty][td]), int(tracey[tx][ty][td]), int(traced[tx][ty][td])
            tx, ty, td = xn,yn,dn

    # print(tracex[0][0][0])



def draw_img(img, x, y):
    screen.blit(img, (x + 5, y + 5))


def draw():
    x, y = 0, 0
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    for i in range(q):
        for j in range(q):
            if grid[i][j] == gr_agent:
                draw_img(agent, x, y)
            elif grid[i][j] == gr_wumpus:
                draw_img(wumpus, x, y)
            elif grid[i][j] == gr_gold:
                draw_img(gold, x, y)
            elif grid[i][j] == gr_pit:
                draw_img(pit, x, y)
            for k in range(4):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, border_color, (x - k, y - k, w, w), 1)
            x = x + w
        x = 0
        y = y + w


def main():
    test()
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mx, my = event.pos
                gy = mx // w
                gx = my // w
                if not grid[gx][gy] == gr_empty:
                    continue
                elif event.button == 1:
                    # Left click
                    grid[gx][gy] = gr_wumpus
                elif event.button == 3:
                    # Scroll slick
                    grid[gx][gy] = gr_gold
                elif event.button == 2:
                    # Middle click
                    grid[gx][gy] = gr_pit
        draw()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(600)


main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).